# Question about proof on faithful character giving rise to abelian $P$-sylow subgroup

Tags: representation-theory

[Faithful character of degree less than p gives abelian p-Sylow groups.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1733746/faithful-character-of-degree-less-than-p-gives-abelian-p-sylow-groups/1733969#1733969)

I have a question about the above question answered by Derek Holts. As I don't have enough reputation I couldn't post my question as a comment to his answer.

In his proof, he starts of by writing $\chi= \sum a_i\chi_i$ where the sum ranges over all irreducible representations of $P$. Then he says that each $\chi_i(1)$ must be a power of $p$, which is also OK. However, since $$\chi(1)=\sum a_i\chi_i(1) < p$$ we must have that $\chi_i(1) =1$ and so all the irreducible representations of $P$ have degree one, hence $P$ is abelian.

My first question is, what if $a_i=0$ for some $i$, then we don't necessarily have $\chi_i(1)=1$. Also, I don't see where we use the fact that $\chi$ is faithful, maybe its to make sure that the coefficients are nonzero? Please help me to sort out my confusion.